# About ios Application loader codesign verification

Tags: ios, loader, verification, codesign

I have uploaded an app to itunes by application loader , and the app's status is  "Waiting For Review".But I am not sure that  I have signed the code with distribution provisioning not with developer provisioning. Is my worry unnecessary？Has the Application loader checked my code signature valid?Does Application loader not permit app signed incorrectly to be uploaded?

Answer (score 2):

If you've made it to the "waiting for review" stage, then you've signed the build with the proper provisioning profile. They catch that sort of stuff at the submit stage. Congrats on submission!